# Select document as root context from a BaseX database by URI

Tags: xquery, basex, xquery-3.1

Might not be difficult, but i cannot find the correct command and syntax:

I have a BaseX database opened that holds several XML documents:

```
/document-uri()
```

looks like this

```
/dirA/dirA1/x01.xml
/dirA/dirA1/x02.xml
/dirA/dirA2/x03.xml
/dirA/dirA3/dirA31/x04.xml
/dirA/dirA3/dirA31/x05.xml
/dirA/dirA3/dirA32/x06.xml
/dirB/dirB1/x07.xml
/dirB/dirB2/x08.xml
/dirC/dirC1/x09.xml
/dirC/dirC2/dirC11/x10.xml
/dirD/dirD1/dirD11/x11.xml
/dirE/dirE1/dirE11/x12.xml
```

What i am looking for is a XQuery to select a document by URI and use it as XPath context, s.th. like this:

```
document("/dirA/dirA1/x01.xml")/root/foo
```

Another one would be super useful as well: select all documents in a dir path (recursively:))

```
document("/dirA/dirA1/")/root/foo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `doc` function so `doc('/dirA/dirA1/x01.xml')` should select the document. There is also the `collection` function which probably allows you to select `collection('/dirA/dirA1')`, the exact use of the collection function is depending on the XQuery processor and e.g. how you set up your DB in BaseX.

So basically the `doc` and the `collection` functions should help in XQuery. Only XSLT has a function named `document` you have used in your samples.

Comment: `doc()` and  `collection()` work fine with BaseX. Thank you!